# How should I interpret $z_1^{-1}$ if $z = e^{j\omega(i)T}$?

Tags: transfer-function, unit-shift

I'm trying to understand how I should create all these $z$ values.

Each $z$ values is equal to $z = e^{j\omega(i)T}$ were $j$ is the complex number (instead of $i$), $\omega(i)$ is the i:th wrequency in radians and $T$ is the sample time.

But when it comes it $z_1^{-1}, z_1^{-2}, z_1^{-3}, \dots , z_1^{-p}$. How should I interpret these then? Is it $z^{-p} = {e^{j\omega(i)T}}^{-p}$ ? Or is the $^{-p}$ just the next number?

For example:
The first row of the system of equations will be
$$G^T(z_1^{-1})z_1^{-1}$$

That means $z_1^{-1} = e^{j\omega(1-1)T}$  becaue $\omega(0)$ is the first frequency and the next value:

$$G^T(z_1^{-1})z_1^{-2}$$

will be $z_1^{-2} = e^{j\omega(2-1)T}$

And it goes on and on:

$$z_1^{-2} = e^{j\omega(2-1)T}$$
$$z_1^{-3} = e^{j\omega(3-1)T}$$
$$z_1^{-4} = e^{j\omega(4-1)T}$$
$$z_1^{-5} = e^{j\omega(5-1)T}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$z_1^{-p} = e^{j\omega(p-1)T}$$

And for $z_2$ it will be:

$$z_2^{-1} = e^{j\omega(1-2)T}$$
$$z_2^{-2} = e^{j\omega(2-2)T}$$
$$z_2^{-3} = e^{j\omega(3-2)T}$$
$$z_2^{-4} = e^{j\omega(4-2)T}$$
$$z_2^{-5} = e^{j\omega(5-2)T}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$z_2^{-p} = e^{j\omega(p-2)T}$$

And all $e^{j\omega(1-2)T}$ that have $\omega(-1)$ or more, will be zero e.g $e^{j\omega(1-2)T} = 0$

Is this correct? I think the image is very confusing.

[image]

**Update:**

I have made a MATLAB/Octave code here that assume that $\omega(i)$ has the length $l$ and the polynoms are $1+p$ for $A$ and $1+p$ for $B$.

```
    % Create the polynomials for A and B
    A = zeros(l, p);
    B = zeros(l, p);
    for i = 1:l
      for j = 1:p
        if(i + j - 1 > l)
          break;
        end
        z = exp(1i*w(i + j - 1)*sampleTime);
        A(i, j) = G(i)*z;
        B(i, j) = z;
      end
    end

   % Add one column of ones to B
   B = [ones(l, 1) B];

   % Find the vector
   AB = linsolve([real([A B]); imag([A B])], [real(G'); imag(G')]);

   % Split
   A = [1; AB(1:p)]
   B = AB(p+1:end)
```

This is how the code should be like instead:

```
% Create the polynomials for A and B
A = zeros(l, p);
B = zeros(l, p);
for i = 1:l
   for j = 1:p
     z = exp(1i*w(i)*(-j)*sampleTime);
     A(i, j) = G(i)*z;
     B(i, j) = z;
   end
end

% Add one column of ones to B
B = [ones(l, 1) B];

% Find the vector
AB = linsolve([real([A B]); imag([A B])], [real(G'); imag(G')]);

% Split
A = [1; AB(1:p)]
B = AB(p+1:end)
```

Comment: It would really help to add some context: what are you trying to do and where did you this matrix from? Your notation seems unusual and needlessly complicated to me but I can't tell what it's actually supposed to be.

Comment: @Hilmar I'm trying to find $A$ and $B$ vectors. It's for system identification.

Comment: That's typically not the way I would do system identification. Where did you get this idea from? What exactly is $G^T$. Please define all the symbols that you are using properly. It looks like an IIR filter but it's really hard to tell

Comment: @Hilmar Here I got that idea from: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/reports/SSFD.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is terrible, but what I *think* is meant is

$$z_i=e^{j\omega_iT}$$

I.e., $z_i$ are complex numbers on the unit circle with angles $\omega_iT$.
This implies

$$z_i^n=e^{j\omega_inT},\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: I aggree that the notation is terrible. But are you sure about $nT$?

Comment: I have never seen a notation like this.

Comment: @Heretic: Yes, I'm sure. That's how you compute powers of complex numbers.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps I should change my MATLAB code then in the orginal post. So all I need to do is to add $n$ e.g if  $n = -2$, then I would have $z_i^{-2} = e^{-j\omega_i2T}$ ?

Comment: See the paper here: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/reports/SSFD.pdf

Comment: @Heretic: Yes, that's how powers work.

Comment: Ok. It was just powers....my misstake. I thought it was some kind of weird notation for "shift".

Comment: Hmm...I don't think it should be power. Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you think my MATLAB code is working above?

Comment: I don't think it should be negative as in the report.

Comment: $z^{-n}$ is a time shift operator. But in the frequency domain it's just a power. Since $z^{-n}$ is a delay of n samples, the negative sign seems correct here. $z^n$ would be a non-causal (i.e. negative) delay